# Hitting a person or ball

Tags: usage

Meaning of hit in the following sentence

> The record for the number of sixes in a Test was smashed in on Sunday when South Africa's Dane Piedt **hit** India's Ravindra Jadeja over midwicket in the clash at Visakhapatnam.

Here does **hit** mean to affect someone? But that seem idiomatic

Answer (score 1):

A ball was hit. The piece is about a cricket match. A batsman (Dane Piedt, South Africa), hit a ball bowled (thrown) by a bowler, (Ravindra Jadeja, India). Piedt hit the ball so hard, and so accurately, that it went over the boundary of the pitch, without touching the ground. This added six runs to South Africa's score. Expressed briefly, Piedt "hit Jadeja for six", or "hit six off Jadeja". "Midwicket" is a particular part of the boundary.

[Cricket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket)